# Nodejs - concurrent or parallel API calls creates duplicates entries in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, asynchronous, duplicates

**Straight Forwardly:**

I am clicking the button two times from the same machine(user) or from the different machine(user) within the span of 1 seconds. It's creating two documents (duplicates).

In short may be how to handle multiple API calls parallelly or concurrently.

**What I suspect:**

1. Nodejs collects the API call -> `db.find(name)` -> Not Found-> Creating New document (Its running)

> Before the above document creation done. Nodejs started executing the next API call.

2. Nodejs collects the API call -> `db.find(name)` -> Not Found -> Creating New document.

***Example Code:***  Here two account with same name is created.

```
    const userPresent = await User.findOne({
      phoneNumber: data.phoneNumber,
    });
    if (userPresent) {
      throw new CustomError("OIC_ERROR_00027", "User already present");
    }
    // new account created
    const newAccount = await new Account({
      name: data.name,
    }).save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I given `autoindex: false` in option while connecting to MongoDB. So The DB was not taking `indexing` commands in mongoose schema. I removed the `autoindex: false` and followed @koodies guidance. Thanks now working !

But Not working when I try to create connection and use it like `db.model("modelName")`

Answer (score 1):

You may try to create a [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/#create-a-unique-index) for your product name. This will cause your product name to not have any duplicates.

```
db.collection.createIndex( {"name":1} , { unique: true } )
```

Comment: But, I don't want the same name to repeat

Comment: yea it will not have any duplicates ... have you even try it out

Comment: Please check the edited code in the question can your solution secure the above problem ? When more or 1000 calls happens at the same time. I am just super curious

Comment: And to my knowledge it just acts as a primary key ?

Comment: By creating a unique index MongoDB prevent any same {name:"name"} document to be created, an error will be returned on your subsequent .save() command with {name:"name"}. So only one instance of said document can be found in your document

Comment: super cool. will check and give tick to the solution. Super Thanks !

Comment: index is not working with schema.index({name: 1}, {unique: true}). Also tried with new database

Comment: My Schema

`const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.set("debug", true);

const purchaseSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
    },
  }
);`

purchaseSchema.index({supplier: 1},{unique: true})

module.exports = mongoose.model("purchase", purchaseSchema);

Comment: I do insert many command for saving

Comment: `name: { type: String, unique: true}`
  - https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-indexes
Do make sure that at the point of creating unique indexes, the field must not have any duplicates.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference. Any other solutions ? Like db restart or any